# Programmatically downloading a file from a filehoster

Tags: delphi, redirect, download, idhttp

I have some files uploaded at a filehoster which I want to download programmatically, using Delphi. They don't require any captchas or the like, normally you simply press a button and you get the file. Let's take [this as an example](http://www56.zippyshare.com/v/5862319/file.html).

Now I thought I could simply take the URL the Download Now - Button is pointing at, use an TIdHTTP.Get request and save it with a MemoryStream / Filestream / whatever. Copying the link address leads to [this site](http://www56.zippyshare.com/d/5862319/811375/bgAvgTable.png), which, when entered into my browser pops up the download prompt.

```
var
  MemStream: TMemoryStream;
  code: string;       // added for solution
  number: integer;    // added for solution
begin
  with TIdHTTP.Create(nil) do
  try
    HandleRedirects := true;
    System.Delete(code,1,AnsiPos('var n =',code)+7);                  // added
    number := StrToInt(AnsiLeftStr(code,AnsiPos(' ',code)-1)) + 1;    // added
    MemStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      // Get('http://www56.zippyshare.com/d/5862319/604061/bgAvgTable.png', MemStream);
      Get(TIdURI.URLEncode('http://www56.zippyshare.com/d/5862319/' + IntToStr(number)
        + '/bgAvgTable.png'), MemStream);       // added for solution
      MemStream.SaveToFile('test.png');
    finally
      MemStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

However, using a checking tool I found that it contains a 302 redirect to the original site, thus when performing the GET-request I have to set HandleRedirects to avoid error messages and I get the HTML code of the original site rather than the file I had suspected.

So, I am kind of confused about how 
   **1)** I somehow get the file from my browser though the URL only contains a 302 redirect to the previous page and 
   **2)** I can achieve the same from within my code. Any chance someone of you might educate me a little there ? ;)

**EDIT**

Thanks to your input I could find the issue, turns out that the address I have to use gets generated using a random number, which is to be found in the original source. So posting a request to get the number first does the trick. I have edited the code accordingly.

Comment: Apparently you're trying to download a png file, but save it as a bmp file.

Comment: @jachguate sorry, typo, but by saving it as an .html I made sure it is the actual code of the previous page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File hosting sites make different tricks to ensure you was not [hotlinking](http://altlab.com/hotlinking.html) and show you advertisement and perhaps counter. There can be

- simple analysis of HTTP Referrer field in the request
- setting and checking session-unique cookies
- having HTTP Forms with hidden one-time values, and Download button would be not the link but the form's Submit action.
- generating one-time hashed URL, and encoding different parameters like your IP and your browser name into it
- maybe more

Tools like USDownloader and JDownloader makes a lot of attempts to circumvent it.

While zippyshare seems to be more liberal, it still cannot afford hotlinking and should implement at least some measures of self-defense.
When analysing traffic - start with absolutely fresh browser loading zippyshare page for the 1st time in its life and check it all.

As i re-load the page few times i see that the number "604061" is different and link keep changing time and again after each reload. You probably have to load the page, parse the link, set the HTTP referer and only then download the file.

You do not show the HTTP traffic logs so it is hard to tell for sure.

Comment: Which format would be suitable for a meaningful traffic log that could be interpreted by me / someone more skilled here ?

Comment: some text on pastebin, preferable you should disable pictures on browsers and plugins, to reduce irrelevant requests - there woud be many of them.

start with getting THE PAGE with delphi and showing its traffic. 
then analyze line but linem read help on HTTP and try to match against the bullets above.

Comment: But - perhaps you could just screw it all, run web-browser inside Delphi and make it load the file for you ? ugly and slow in runtime, yet faster to code. Instead of re-implementing this all.

Comment: I could very well try the 2nd approach, however this seems to be a last resort if I can't get it to work any other way.

I wasn't wondering about how to share it most efficiently though but how to actually create it, like, what kind of logs are you talking about ? Wireshark session, Fiddler, something else ?

Comment: EDIT: Thanks to your input I was able to find a solution, as it would probably get burried down here I edited the opening post. Accepted your answer because you gave the most input, thanks to jachguate too though.

Comment: yeah, tools like that. decade ago i used Proxomitron, but it fails at my newer win7x64 dunno why. I also use Membrane Monitor. Fiddler must have been good thing, but i fail to make it intercept anything but MSIE, which is of little interest to me.

Comment: Well, i think under "As i re-load the page" i did gave solution, surely i was not obliged to make exactly the code. And the code pattern u search in the page looks so generic to me, that i hope you would not get false positives after every web-page redesign. Actually i think it would be better to parse the page's HTML, get that "download" button and copy URL from its properties.

Answer (score 1):

The server may be checking for some trace to avoid the file to be downloaded programmatically.

It may be anything the hostmaster wants to check, from a wide range of possibilities, but the most typical check is the referrer.

When you navigate in a web browser from one page to another using an link, the browser adds the first page as a referrer to the second page in the request header.

Indy have support for you to add a referrer:

```
IdHTTP1.Request.Referer := 'http://www.any.other.page';
```

If the check fails, the server script just redirects the input to the donwload page. This is done to show advertising or to filfull other goals of the file hosting service.

Comment: sounds plausible, however adding this line before the get-request with the previous address does not change anything

Comment: @Heina Thus, the hostmaster is checking different things. It's up to you to figure out what it is, so analyze the traffic that's going on between your browser and the server when a successful download occurs.

Comment: Are you sure the download occurs within a get and not a post?

Comment: he can disable HTTP Referrer in browser and see if that would change the behaviour. URLs are one-time, but what is hashed in them no one knows.

Comment: just launch two different browsers and pass the link from one to another - same behavior. So actually there may be anything in the HTTP logs, we did not saw them